# Android Robotium Recorder - "Signature Mismatch. Please reselect APK"

Tags: android, apk, signature, robotium-recorder

I am trying to test an android app on emulator using `Robotium Recorder`, and when clicked on `New Robotium Test` button, the android app APK gets properly installed on the emulator running and after installation of the APK, it gives me the following error:

> Signature Mismatch. Please re select APK.

I don't know how to get around this problem, due to which I'm not able to record any of the test for the android app.

Comment: Hi ASAP S, Please help me! I am stuck,